# Combine two events on different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textArea where you type a message, and to submit it you have to press a button.
The whole submitting process will be in JS/jQuery. For now the submission will be triggered only by the onclick event of the submit button.

```
$(".btn-success").click(function () {
        // Submit Code
 });
```

Now I want to combine :

```
$('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            // Same Submit Code
        }
    });
```

So that when the user presses 'enter', the message is submited, without having to repeat the function twice.

Any help ? Couldn't find anything on the forum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the functions were exactly the same end the events occure on same element I was going to recommend joining them with `on`:

```js
$('#element').on('click change other_events', function(e){...});
```

Yet, as this is not the case, ***The Simple Answer is Creating a submit function and calling it in the different events callbacks***

```js
function submit() {
    // your code
}
$(".btn-success").click(function () {
    submit()
});
$('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        submit()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the function was born to do it give it a name:

```js
function onSubmit() {
  // Submit Code
}

$(".btn-success").click(onSubmit)
$('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    onSubmit()
  }
});
```

> if in function onSubmit use `this` please replace with $(".btn-success")[0]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a standard named function:

```
$(".btn-success").click(doIt);
$('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
        if(e.which == 13) doIt();
    });

function doIt() {
// can be called from anywhere
}
```